# Using javascript in a view to enable textbox on radiobutton state for each items in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this view with 2 radiobuttons strongly-typed to a model, and I wish to enable / disable textbox fields depending on the state of those radiobuttons.

Here is the view and the script I've been working on right now:

```
@model IList<MyApp.Models.ObjInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SendItems";
}

<h2>Ebay Items</h2>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function dostate1() {
        $("#textfield1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#textfield2").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#textfield3").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    function dostate2() {
        $("#textfield1").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#textfield2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#textfield3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        alert("The document is ready");
        if ($("#state1").is(":checked")) {
            dostate1();
        } else {
            dostate2();
        }

        $("#state1").click(function (){
            alert("Auction radio button has been clicked");
            dostate1();
        });
        $("#state2").click(function () {
            alert("Buy It Now radio button has been clicked");
            dostate2();
        });
    });
    </script>
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ManageItems", "Item Inventory"))
    {
       (...)
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <p>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].m_OtrObj.m_ObjName)</td>
                        <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_State, "State 1", new {id = "state1", style ="width: 50px"})</td>
                        <td>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x[i].m_State, "State 2", new {id = "state2", style ="width: 50px"})</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].m_Field1, new{id = "textField1", style = "width:200px"})
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].m_Field2, new {id = "textField2", style = "width:200px"})
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].m_Field3, new {id ="textField3", style = "width:200px" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </p>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Do Something"/>
    }
</p>
```

Right now I have 2 main problems:

1. Clicking on each radiobutton actually disable the fields I wish to have disabled, but do not activate the other fields;
2. The script actually runs only when a button is clicked, but should run at start to avoid field 1 being active since by default the "state 1" radio button is enabled.

I'm **REALLY** a newbie as to javascript, so can anyone help me out? Thanks!!

EDIT **

I've modified the script to show you the evolution so far, thanks to everyone who helped out, the script works, but only for the first item in the list. Taking into account that it's a list of object (see @model), how can I affect each items in the list individually?

Comment: When you say "on every items in a list." what does your list look like?

Comment: Like the @for loop indicates, it's a list of items from my view model.

Comment: I'd like to affect each items on the list with this script, yet only the first item is affected...

Comment: Herve, see my updated answer - hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so:

1. you need to enable the radio buttons by using jQuery's removeAttr function (http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

   ```
   alert("state1 radio button has been clicked");
   $("#textField1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   $("#textField2").removeAttr("disabled");
   $("#textField3").removeAttr("disabled");
   ```

   this is because it's the presence of the "disabled" attribute that disables controls.
2. if you break your enable/disable code out into functions:

   ```
   function doState1() {
     $("#textField1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $("#textField2").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#textField3").removeAttr("disabled");
   }

   function doState2() {
     $("#textField1").removeAttr("disabled");
     $("#textField2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
     $("#textField3").attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
     doState1();

     $("#state1").change(function (){
       doState1();
     });
     $("#state2").change(function() {
       doState2();
     });
   });
   ```

you can then call them when the doc is ready, and hook them into the click actions.

**Edit**
To repeat this for sets of buttons + fields, I would have your loop generate ids that are unique to each element, e.g.

```
<input type="radio" id="state_1_1">State 1_1
<input type="radio" id="state_2_1">State 2_1
<input type="text" id="textField_1_1">Text 1_1
<input type="text" id="textField_2_1">Text 2_1
<input type="text" id="textField_3_1">Text 3_1

<input type="radio" id="state_1_2">State 1_2
<input type="radio" id="state_2_2">State 2_2
<input type="text" id="textField_1_2">Text 1_2
<input type="text" id="textField_2_2">Text 2_2
<input type="text" id="textField_3_2">Text 3_2
```

and then change the code to use a "search start of id" selector and split the id to obtain the set and state/text field number:

```
function doState1(theid) {
    var idarr = theid.split("_");
    var state = idarr[1];
    var idval = idarr[2];
    $("#textField_1_" + idval).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#textField_2_" + idval).removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#textField_3_" + idval).removeAttr("disabled");
}

function doState2(theid) {
    var idarr = theid.split("_");
    var state = idarr[1];
    var idval = idarr[2];
    $("#textField_1_" + idval).removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#textField_2_" + idval).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#textField_3_" + idval).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("#state_1_1").is(":checked")) {
        doState1("state_1_1");
    } else {
        doState2("state_2_1");
    }

    $('input[id^="state_1_"]').change(function () {
        doState1(this.id);
    });

    $('input[id^="state_2_"]').change(function () {
        doState2(this.id);
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/raad/4vHBv/17/

Comment: I have one small problem with the script you gave me. Right now, only the first item in the list is affected by these methods, and I need to do this on every items in a list. Is there any way to change this so that it will affect every items in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    alert("The document is ready");

    $("#state1").change(function (){ // use change event instead of click
        alert("state1 radio button has been changed");
        // use prop instead of attr and always use the disabled attribute 
        // (there is not enabled). Use true/false to alter its state
        $("#textField1").prop("disabled", true); 
        $("#textField2").prop("disabled", false);
        $("#textField3").prop("disabled", false);
    }).trigger('change'); // trigger a change event since it is the default 

    $("#state2").change(function() { // use change event instead of click
        alert("state2 radio button has been changed");
        $("#textField1").prop("disabled", false); 
        $("#textField2").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#textField3").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Herve S, I forgot the `change` parameter in the `.trigger()` call.. Updated answer and demo at http://jsfiddle.net/DvuBN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is already answered above. As for the second one I would suggest moving the state checking to a function like this:

```
function checkState(){
    if($('#state1').is(':checked')){
       //do stuff...
    }
}
```

And then run the function once on document ready and every time the state of the radio buttons is changed.

Comment: I like this! I will try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First , You have to understand the there is no such attribute by the name of 'enable'. For enable the html element , you have to remove the disabled attribute from fields.

If you want to change your field from disabled to enable state , then just do as i am writing:
   $("#textField2").removeAttr("disabled");
   $("#textField3").removeAttr("disabled");

Above code will enable the the Textbox with id "#textField2" and "#textField3"